# SASS scss to css does not render var to hex color

Tags: sass

I'm new to sass/scss and stumbled upon a strange thing:

when I put the following in style.scss file:

```
:root {
  --red:#ff4f70;
}

.card-title-success {
  color: var(--red);
}
```

and run

```
sass style.scss style.css :
```

it renders style.css without replacing the var with #color like #ff4f70 leaving it exactly like in style.scss! here it is content of style.css:

```
.card .card-title-success {
  color: var(--red); }
```

How do I make sass to render #ff4f70 into css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `--red` syntaxe is a css's syntaxe, for scss you must use :
`$red:#ff4f70`, which means your code must look like this:

```
:root {
  $red:#ff4f70;
}

.card-title-success {
  color: $red;
}
```

Notice that scss don't use the function `var()` you put the link directly.
You can read more about sass/scss variables here https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables